# How to get cookies from mechanize to use in pdfkit

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize-python, python-pdfkit

Does anyone know how to get a cookie that I have logged into using `mechanize` browser, so that I can use those urls in `pdfkit`? I have looked around a bit, but can't manage to see how to get a cookie in the right format and pass it to `pdfkit.from_url`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wkhtmltopdf` support set cookie with `--cookie` option, extract cookies from `mechanize browser`, pass to `wkhtmltopdf` with argument `options` of `pdfkit.from_url`:

```
cj = br.cookiejar # assume `br` is a `browser` intance
ops = {'cookie': [(c.name, urllib.quote(c.value)) for c in cj]}
pdfkit.from_url('url', options=ops)
```